# "pipenv install" causes "OSError: Command .../python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, pipenv

Running:

```
mkdir pythontest
cd pythontest
pipenv install requests
```

causes:

```
 "OSError: Command .../python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1"
```

Some additional information:

- Mac OS
- I do not seem to have conda

Answer (score -1):

The python version installed by default in Mac is 2.7 which is not a recommended version to build newer applications.

Please install the latest python version (which is 3.7.0) from https://www.python.org/

Then try "pip3.7 install requests"

Comment: I am working on a project that uses 2.7. I want to create a test project where I can play around with things for that project, so I want to use 2.7, not 3.7.